# Android Studio Reload not performed Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[image]

I have an issue when I try to save any modifications on a new project, the hot reload doesn t work on save, because he has an issue that I can t find

I need to mention that I do not modified anything in the project, just started 2 hours ago and searched for the solution

I just tried to modify the title and nothing more first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android Studio on the top left corner choose File -> Invalidate Caches...

Then you will see a modal
[image]

check both option and press the "Invalidate and Restart" button.

When the Android studio starts again, Re-run your application and check if the hot-reload works properly.

That worked for me.

Comment: Don't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a banner on top that says you haven't run pub get. You can press the button on that banner to run the command (Get dependencies).

This is likely because you changed your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Another thing you can try is to stop and restart, this is sometimes necessary. If this also doesn't work, try to clean using the command `flutter clean` and/or restart Android Studio

Comment: Yeah, sure, i've tried it, it doesn t matter, because he does it and after "Get dependencies", the banner sticks there

Comment: I've added another thing you can try. Stop and restart the app, this is sometimes necessary. If this also doesn't work, try to clean using the command `flutter clean` or restart Android Studio